# The geometry of algorithms with acyclicity constraints

Tags: differential-geometry, graph-theory, optimization, manifolds

I would like to know whether there is any way to apply similar techniques from [Riemannian gradient descent on certain matrix manifolds](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Eedelman/publications/geometry_of_algorithms.pdf) to [adjacency matrices of DAGs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01422v2).

The idea of the latter paper is to introduce a new constraint,
$$
h(W) = \operatorname{tr}(\exp(W \circ W)) - d \ge 0,
$$

such that $h(W) = 0$ iff $W$ represents a DAG, for $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. (With $\circ$ being the Hadamard product.)

Now, $h$ isn't convex, but at least continuous and differentiable. Could the Riemannian methods be applied to $\{W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d} \mid h(W) = 0\}$, so that instead of optimizing functions over $\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ subject to the constraint, one can directly use a gradient method on the constrained space?

Unfortunately my knowledge of differential geometry is very limited beyond some geometric intuition.  There's no concrete use case, I am merely exploring the idea.